# How to implement the Seq.grouped(size:Int): Seq[Seq[A]] for Dataset in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to try to implement the 
`def grouped(size: Int): Iterator[Repr]` that `Seq` has but for `Dataset` in Spark.

So the input should be `ds: Dataset[A], size: Int` and output `Seq[Dataset[A]]` where each of the `Dataset[A]` in the output can't be bigger than `size`.

How should I proceed ? I tried with `repartition` and `mapPartitions` but I am not sure where to go from there.

Thank you.

*Edit*: I found the `glom` method in `RDD` but it produce a `RDD[Array[A]]` how do I go from this to the other way around `Array[RDD[A]]` ?

Answer (score 1):

here you go, something that you want

```
/*
{"countries":"pp1"}
{"countries":"pp2"}
{"countries":"pp3"}
{"countries":"pp4"}
{"countries":"pp5"}
{"countries":"pp6"}
{"countries":"pp7"}
   */

import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext};


object SparkApp extends App {

  override def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application").setMaster("local").set("spark.ui.enabled", "false")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

    val dataFrame: DataFrame = sqlContext.read.json("/data.json")

    val k = 3

    val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("grouped").orderBy("countries")

    val newDF = dataFrame.withColumn("grouped", lit("grouping"))

    var latestDF = newDF.withColumn("row", row_number() over windowSpec)

    val totalCount = latestDF.count()
    var lowLimit = 0
    var highLimit = lowLimit + k

    while(lowLimit < totalCount){
      latestDF.where(s"row <= $highLimit and row > $lowLimit").show(false)
      lowLimit = lowLimit + k
      highLimit = highLimit + k
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I found but I am not sure if that can works reliably:

```
  override protected def batch[A](
    input:     Dataset[A],
    batchSize: Int
  ): Seq[Dataset[A]] = {
    val count = input.count()
    val partitionQuantity = Math.ceil(count / batchSize).toInt

    input.randomSplit(Array.fill(partitionQuantity)(1.0 / partitionQuantity), seed = 0)
  }
```

Comment: It's not reliable, as you suspected. randomSplit does not guarantee equal batch size, so there'll be batches larger than the given size.